# Unreal Error: Game target is required with -cook or -cookonthefly

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

On Unreal Engine 4.26.2, I am trying to package a Blueprint/C++ mixture project for Win64.

However, I have encountered the following error:

```
LogMainFrame: Project does not require temp target
LogLauncherProfile: Found promoted target with matching version at ../../../Engine/Binaries/Win64/UE4Game-Win64-Shipping.target
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Running AutomationTool...
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Parsing command line: -ScriptsForProject="C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Unreal Projects/foo.uproject" BuildCookRun -nocompileeditor -installed -nop4 -project="C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Unreal Projects/foo.uproject" -coo
k -stage -archive -archivedirectory=C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Win32UnrealBuilds -package -ue4exe="C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Cmd.exe" -ddc=InstalledDerivedDataBackendGraph -pak -prereqs -nodebuginfo -targetplatform=Win64 -clientconfig=Shipping -utf8output
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Setting up ProjectParams for C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Unreal Projects\foo.uproject
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): ERROR: Game target not found. Game target is required with -cook or -cookonthefly
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):        (see C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.26\Log.txt for full exception trace)
PackagingResults: Error: Game target not found. Game target is required with -cook or -cookonthefly
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

The relevant section of the full exception trace is:

```
BuildCookRun.SetupParams: Setting up ProjectParams for C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Unreal Projects\foo.uproject
InternalUtils.SafeFileExists: SafeFileExists C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\UAT\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.26\Rules\UATRules24283721.dll=False
DynamicCompilation.RequiresCompilation: Compiling C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\UAT\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.26\Rules\UATRules24283721.dll: Assembly does not exist
...
Program.Main: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown)
```

Is there a conventional reason "Game target not found" is hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not clear why it worked, copying the default projectname.Target.cs file in the `Source` directory and renaming it projectnameGame.Target.cs (and also change the internal class name of that file to match) seemed to do the trick. There are now 3 `Target.cs` files in the `Source` directory.

- projectname.Target.cs
- projectnameGame.Target.cs
- projectnameEditor.Target.cs

At that point everything worked again... this seems weird but it works!